# Create a countdown timer and redirect to another page after countdown comes to zero

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I want create a countdown timer for som sections of my asp.net sites with javascript. 
The timer starts from various minutes or seconds. After countdown comes to zero, I want stop the timer tick and do somethings like redirect to another page.
I've found this code from google and it's ok, but never stop after countdown comes to zero. please help me to fix this bug.

```
<head>
<script>
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
        setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            if (timer-- < 0) {
                //window.location = "http://www.example.com";
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
            display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time">05:00</span></div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Uh in addition to what everyone answered, you do know that this code isn't a timer, right? It always fires after 1000 ms

Comment: thanks , whatever you said ... but this code played as a countdown for my site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to clear what setInterval return. Something like this.

```html
<script>
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
        var end =setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            if (--timer < 0) {
                //window.location = "http://www.example.com";
                clearInterval(end);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        var fiveMinutes = 5,
            display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Registration closes in <span id="time">05:00</span></div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Gotrank's accepted answer is great - one small bug though:

```
    var fiveMinutes = 5,
```

...should be...

```
    var fiveMinutes = 300,
```

...for five minutes (it is currently 5 seconds). I would have commented, but I don't have enough reputation points yet.

Comment: It's true, but I tought no one wants to wait 5 min to see the result. :)

Comment: it's a matter of clarity for any beginners who stumble upon your code and are puzzled as to why fivemins aren't really five minutes :)